# Rails - Understanding the Querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails, and I am given a code, but I do not understand what it means (I am actually just trying to understand the Rails code because I am tasked to use the same logic inside another program)

here is the code

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
users = User.where(account_id: ids)
output = Worksheet.where(created_by: users).as_json(only: [:created_at, :id]).group_by_week(week_start: :monday) 
{|w| w["created_at"]}
```

i am not sure if I am following along, but from what i understand, it seems like i am querying the users with id 1, 2, 3, and finding the worksheets that are created by said users, and grouping them by week. However, I do not really understand what the 'only: [:created_at, :id]' does, but I checked through the columns, and there were columns 'created_at' and 'id' inside the worksheet table. Also, I am totally lost about what the below code is about

```
{|w| w["created_at"]}
```

and finally, is it possible to let me know what the output of the program would be like? thanks all!

Comment: `{|w| w["created_at"]}` is chained at the end of the line before. `group_by_week` returns a hash probably that is cycled over by `{|w| w["created_at"]}`

Comment: thank you for replying! oh so the group_by_week returns sort of an array? of those stuff that are within the same week? am i understanding it correctly? and the {|w| w["created_at"]} is added on after that to loop through the 'grouped' data? in that case, can i ask, what does w['created_at'] do? does it just extract out that particular column? meaning that the output of the code above would be an array, where each array contains all the 'created-at' column data for those within the same week?

Comment: Have you read the docs, there are a few examples there? https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: Yes i looked thru the docs, but I am confused about the output for the group_by_week after it has ran through the {|w| w["created_at"]}. Looking at the docs, the examples show a hash after .count was called after group_by_week, but in the case of the function called above, wouldnt each row have a different 'created_at' value? hence leading to an array within a hash? or am i misunderstanding something? sorry im really new to rails

Comment: The best way to learn all of this is to play around with it the `rails c` the Rails console. You hopefully have access to some data to work with.

Comment: okay i'll go try to play around with it in the rails console, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as_json(only: [:created_at, :id])` part says "convert this result to json but I only want those two columns." [Documentation.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

The `group_by_week(week_start: :monday)` takes a block, which is what the `{ |w| w["created_at"] }` part is. It will go through each result from all the previous operations, assign each in turn to `w`, and then use `w["created_at"]` for the `group_by_week` function (for comparison purposes, most likely).

Comment: thank you so much for answering! i see, so in the end, the output would be a dictionary of arrays? where each key is the week, and the values for each key is an array of the 'created_at' column of the respective rows? in that case, does the 'id' column get retained in the output?

Comment: A guess would be that the value of each key is an array with the json objects consisting of `created_at` and `id`values. As mentioned in the other comment thread, try it in a rails console :)